# How to sendMessage directly to any User (i have user_id) by bot using Telegram Bot Api

Tags: php, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I've User ID's of multiple people. I want to send them a message using my BOT but, the problem is I don't have chat_id of an individual user because they haven't initiated a chat with the bot. Is there a way I can send a Direct message using User_ID (not with chat_id).

Comment: Where did you get the user ID list?

Comment: I've different Telegram Groups. When new users join a group I'm saving their data in the database.

Comment: your bot can't be the initiator of the conversation. you can only send a message to users that have pressed the start button and have not stopped the bot yet.

Answer (score 2):

> Bots can't initiate conversations with users. A user must either add them to a group or send them a message first. People can use telegram.me/ links or username search to find your bot.

[telegram.org](https://core.telegram.org/bots#4-how-are-bots-different-from-humans)

Comment: But, I want to get rid of these steps. I Just want to start a conversation right away with the bot.

Comment: It‘s clearly stated that this is not possible at the moment.